# Clarification about moving arguments

Tags: robust-commands

I was reading in `latex2e` about the use of `\protect`.  In section 13.8 it mentions "expressions in `tabular` and `array` enviornments" as examples of moving arguments. I was a bit surprised by this.  Could someone clarify what's meant here?  Or, why that's the case?

I tried experimenting, such as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\ae@suchthat{\mid}
\newcommand\set[1]{%%
  \begingroup
    \let\suchthat\ae@suchthat
      \{\,#1\,\}%%
  \endgroup
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lc}
This & $\set{x\in X \suchthat x>42}$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

But there doesn't seem to be a problem here.  What am I misunderstanding about fragile vs robust?

Comment: Related question, [macros - What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands? When and why do we need \protect? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands-when-and-why-do-we-n?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The manual should mention “`@`-expressions in `tabular` and `array`”, to be consistent with the official manual by Leslie Lamport. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l@{ \resizebox{2mm}{!}{$x$} }l}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

will end up with a typical error message due to fragile commands in moving arguments:

```
! Use of \@array doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar ... \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.5 ...in{tabular}{l@{ \resizebox{2mm}{!}{$x$} }l}
```

If we use `\protect\resizebox` we get no error.

Quoting from “LaTeX, A Document Preparation System”, page 168:

> ### C.1.3 Fragile commands
>
> Commands are classified as either *robust* and *fragile*. [...] The following are all the commands and environments with moving arguments:
>
> - [...]
> - An `@` in `array` or `tabular` environment. (Although `@` is not a command, fragile commands in an `@`-expression must be `\protect`'ed as if they were in a moving argument.)

Comment: The manual I got is what popped up when I called `texdoc latex2e` from the command line.  Which manual are you referring to?  I can't seem to find it

Comment: @A.Ellett It's the official manual by L. Lamport: “LaTeX, A Document Preparation System”. OK, the unofficial manual misses `@` in front of “expressions” (it uses it in section 9.24).